# The `read` builtin hangs indefinitely when used with `timeout`

Tags: bash, shell, sudo, timeout

The script below works perfectly with `bash` but not with `sudo bash` or `sh`. Pressing `enter` or `^C` won't work. Only `^\` and `^Z` work, but not with `sudo bash`.

```
printf '#!/bin/sh\nread var\n' > myscript
chmod +x myscript
sh -c "timeout -k 1 10 ./myscript"
# it does work when `bash` is used instead of `sh`
```

I know I can use `read -t 10`. (This is not available in `sh` and works *only* if I stop using `timeout` anyway.) But the reason I'm using `timeout` has nothing to do with `read`. I need it for (other stuff in) `myscript`. I don't need a workaround but an explanation for the `bash`/`sudo bash` thing and hopefully a solution for `timeout` and `read`.

Comment: With which implementation and version of sh, bash and timeout? On what system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know yet why this is so, but has something to do with how different shells execute and treat signals. Apparently, it looks like this is **some** solution:

```
sh -c "timeout --foreground -k 1 5 ./myscript"
```

The same with `sudo bash`:

```
sudo bash -c "timeout --foreground -k 1 5 ./myscript"
```

`man timeout` has this explained so:

```
--foreground

       when not running timeout directly from a shell prompt,

       allow COMMAND to read from the TTY and get TTY signals; in  this
       mode, children of COMMAND will not be timed out
```

I'm not sure what this all means, nor what the consequences are, but maybe this helps you or someone else will explain.